# Conditions for "equal cardinality $\Rightarrow$ equal (finite) measure"?

Tags: measure-theory

Suppose that $A$ and $B$ are $\mu$-measurable sets with $\mu(A\cup B) < \infty$.

What additional conditions (on $A$ and $B$ and/or $\mu$) are necessary for the implication

$$\mathrm{card}(A) = \mathrm{card}(B) \;\;\; \Rightarrow \;\;\; \mu(A) = \mu(B)$$

to hold?

---

This question was motivated by trying to fill the gaps in a *very brief and sketchy* proof of a theorem about Brownian motion that I heard in a talk recently.  One step in this proof tacitly relied on the implication in this post's title.  Unfortunately, the proof was as sketchy about its initial assumptions as it was about its deductions.  Hence the (perhaps excessive) generality of the question above.

Comment: Interesting question. My uneducated guess says something only slightly short of equality, by examining the case of $\Bbb R$: all open intervals have the same cardinality. Maybe in general spaces though there's more in-betweens.

Comment: I don't think that a satisfying answer can be given to the question in the general form. Do you have more specific assumptions on $\mu$? For example on $\Bbb{R}^n$ with Lebesgue measure, any set of positive measure has the cardinality of the continuum, but two sets of positive measure need not have the same measure. This is also true for a large class of different measures on $\Bbb{R}^n$, e.g. any measure $\mu$ with $d \mu = f d\lambda$ with $f >0$ (almost) everywhere and $\lambda$ the Lebesgue measure.

Comment: @PhoemueX: I've edited my post in response to your comment.